# Use HTACCESS File to limit access to IP only half working

Tags: apache-httpd, ip, htaccess

I am trying to use my HTACCESS file to block all IP's but the ones I want to whitelist.

Below is my HTACCESS FILE:

```
<LIMIT GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
# whitelist Boston IP
allow from 199.xx.xx.xx
# whitelist NY IP
allow from 199.xx.xx.xx
# whitelist SF IP
allow from 96.xx.xx.xx
</LIMIT>
```

To test I did not include the IP I would access the site from. When I do this I am still seeing data load from the site but there is no theme or styles associated with the data.

**Question**: How do I set it up so unless your IP is whitelisted you do not see the site at all?

Comment: Conclusion: the problem is not the `LIMIT` clause, but what you apply it to.

Comment: I am seeing my issue now. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The [Require Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) can be used when `mod_authz_core` is loaded:

```
 <Limit GET>
 # whitelist Boston IP
 Require ip 199.xx.xx.xx
 # whitelist NY IP
 Require ip 199.xx.xx.xx
 # whitelist SF IP
 Require ip 96.xx.xx.xx
 </Limit>
```

Or just one line:

```
 <Limit GET>
 #          Boston       NY           SF
 Require ip 199.xx.xx.xx 199.xx.xx.xx 96.xx.xx.xx
 </Limit>
```